# group_by returning only 1 value for all groups in R

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

Hoping someone can help me with trouble shooting. I have asked a similar question before and applied the answer to a new dataset. I'm grouping my data by ID, then asking it to average 3 vectors. The problem is that the output is the same for all groups.

This is the code I am using:

```
 a <- first %>% 
   group_by(herd_id) %>% 
 summarize(X = mean(first$X), Y = mean(first$Y),Z = mean(first$Z))
```

and this is a sample the output I get:

```
        id   X     Y     Z
<int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1       2 9622.  375.    311.
 2       5 9622.  375.    311.
 3       7 9622.  375.    311.
 4      10 9622.  375.    311.
 5      11 9622.  375.    311.
 6      14 9622.  375.    311.
```

My original dataset is very large, but each ID group is made up of approximately 80 rows (records) and the records for each vector are unique.

My goal is to have the average of each ID group for X, Y and Z.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Is the issue that you are passing a vector of values that is not grouped (`first$X`) to the mean function? Try removing the `first$` from each and see if it works? Hard to test without an example dataset.

Comment: Yep! That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that you are passing a vector of values that is not grouped (first$X) to the mean function? Try removing the first$ from each and see if it works? Hard to test without an example dataset. – Brigadeiro

Answer (score 0):

We could do this `across`

```
library(dplyr)
first %>% 
  group_by(herd_id) %>% 
  summarize(across(c(X, Y, Z), mean), .groups = 'drop')
```